# How to migrate to AudioWorkletNode from ScriptProcessorNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

At the moment I have the following code

```
AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext({latencyHint: 'interactive'});
processor = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
processor.connect(context.destination);
context.resume();
```

I need to migrate the AudioWorkletNode. The main function here is the "createScriptProcessor". I am struggling to find the equivalent of this.
Please help!

Answer (score 3):

It becomes two lines:

```
await context.audioWorklet.addModule( url_worklet );
processor = new AudioWorkletNode( context , 'worklet-processor', {} );
```

And the content of the "processor.onaudioprocess" function goes to an external object, but you can still write it in the same script as follows:

```
let url_worklet = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob([ '(', function(){

  class WorkletProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor { 
    constructor (options) { super(); }
    process(inputs, outputs) {

      console.log( inputs[0][0] ); // the onaudioprocess code here

      return true; 
    }
  }
  registerProcessor('worklet-processor', WorkletProcessor);

}.toString(), ')()' ], { type: 'application/javascript' } ) );
```

The names "WorkletProcessor" and "'worklet-processor'" can be edited.

Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `createScriptProcessor`, you need to something more complicated.  You can find a couple of [examples in the spec itself](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioWorklet-Examples).  There are [other demos](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/) with the basic [Hello Audio Worklet](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/web-audio-samples/audio-worklet/basic/hello-audio-worklet/) being a good place to start.